# detecting browser close all conditions

Tags: javascript, asp.net

This question has been asked many times before but none of the previous ones hit all the issues.  I have a shopping cart that I store in session state.  I'd like to detect when the user leaves the site so I can ask if they'd like to save their cart.  I'd prefer not to automatically store the cart, I hate sites that I re-visit and there's all this leftover stuff in the cart that I'm no longer interested in.

I've tried onbeforeunload but it fires when the user hits the back/previous buttons.  Is there any way from within onbeforeunload I can determine the url where the browser will be going next?  Then I can check if it is local and ignore it, otherwise if leaving the site for good a prompt can be displayed.

Maybe I am not getting something?  How do you handle this situation?

Comment: You could also write a script to clean out all carts that are over a day old that runs every night.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do you handle this situation?

**You don't.**

Use a session timeout to clear the shopping cart.

Besides, what if the user accidentally closes the site? Their cart would automatically be cleared, which makes for terrible UX.

Comment: I'm going to re-think this, the requested behavior came out of study group with customers, the phobes wanted a dialog... thanks for your comments.